# Подписка на событие в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Есть UserControl, грубо говоря, состоящий из нескольких кнопок. Обработчики событий для части из них определены. Как из из XAML подписаться на событие от других кнопок, для которых не назначен обработчик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практика подписывания на события не совсем сочетается с WPF, но тем не менее...

Создаёте RoutedEvent на уровне UserControl'а своего, а потом в XAML подписываетесь, что именно не получается?

Codebehind UserControl:

```
/// <summary>Событие изменения даты</summary>
public static readonly RoutedEvent DateTimeChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DateTimeChanged", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<DateTime?>), typeof(DatePicker));
```

XAML:

```
        <controls:DatePicker 
            DateTimeChanged="dpFrom_DateTimeChanged_1" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            MaxDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" 
            DateTime="{Binding From}" />
```

Comment: Может я просто не так выражаю свою мысль. Хочется из окна, в котором размещен контрол делать что-то типа:
<myConrtol: conrol deleteBtnClick="ondeleteButtonClick" /> тем самым я мог бы назначить обработчик именно на кнопку deleteBtn. Можно немного подробнее про создание RoutedEvent. Спасибо.

Comment: Придётся создавать событие для "проброски". 

    public static readonly RoutedEvent DeleteButtonClick = // ...

И в обработчике уже подписываться на событие самой кнопки.

Вообще событие Click у кнопок заменено на систему команд, которыми куда предпочтительнее пользоваться...

Comment: Из XAML - никак. Зачем Вам вообще привязка к конкретной кнопке, если Вы UserControl создаёте? Какое у него назначение в этом случае?

Comment: Пишу что-то вроде bindingnavigator'a. Перемещение по гриду сделал, а кнопки создания/удаления записи хочу оставить пользователю, чтоб он смог определить обработчики на эти кнопки сам.

Comment: У Вас пользователь код писать будет? Или всё-таки выбирать из заложенных Вами вариантов?

Пример создания RoutedEvent и подписывания из XAML я привёл, его не достаточно? Если так требуется подписывание именно на нажатия клавиш, то и создайте нужное количество RoutedEvent в зависимости от того, сколько у Вас там кнопок. Вот только если помимо Click захочется ещё MouseMove, DragEnter и т.д. и т.п., придётся и их пробрасывать.

Comment: Пользователь в данном случае я, предполагается использовать не в одном проекте и в зависимости от проекта довешивать свою функциональность. Сейчас пробую собрать в одно все здесь сказанное.

Comment: Вроде все получилось. Помогла еще ссылка http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752288.aspx Может кому понадобится. Спасибо! И за оперативность отдельное спасибо :)